# SP 2010 CSOM: Differences between File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn) and File.Publish("")?

Tags: 2010, publishing, check-in

In the SharePoint 2010 Client-Side Object Model, both

```
File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
```

and

```
File.Publish("");
```

appear to do the same thing. Are there any differences, advantages of using one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What i believe, both are different one is for checkin documents and other is for publishing.

**Check In**

1. Check In/Check Out is a policy to avoid confusion while editing
   documents, you perform the Check In to unlock the file/page so that
   other users can edit it, at the same, you must set which kind of
   version you should check in(major version or minor version).[Checks the file in to a document library based on the check-in type.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.checkin(v=office.14).aspx)

**Publish**

2. Perform this action to publish the page/file to published major
   version.[Submits the file for content approval with the specified comment.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.publish(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`File.CheckIn` - Allows to only check in the file

`File.Publish` - This will this will do a Major Checkin and submits for approval.

Comment: File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn) also submits for approval.

Comment: Ok. In that case I don't see any difference 